# <%# Eval("State") %> or <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "state")%>

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, eval

What is the difference between having

```java
<%# Eval("State") %>
```

in your `aspx` page, versus having

```java
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "State") %>
```

in your `aspx` page?

Comment: Now you have your answer... and it was echo 2 times :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`Eval("State")` is a simplified form of the `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "State")` syntax. It only works inside of data-bound template controls.

For more info, see [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx).

Answer (score 12):

There is no difference. The "Eval" method is just a shortcut for the DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "blah") method.

Answer (score 10):

There are a lot of differences between `<%# Eval %>` and `<%# DataBinder.Eval %>` under the covers, even though [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx#Anchor_1) states that using `Eval` (`TemplateControl.Eval` to be exact) actually calls `DataBinder.Eval` and that their task is to do exactly the same job.

That is correct, but using just `Eval` means that ASP.NET itself resolves the object that is databound. It does this internally with a stack where items are added when `Control.DataBind()` is called. The trick is that this happens only if the `Page` property of the control is non-`null` at that point.

If the `Page`-managed stack isn't up to date when you get to the point that `DataItem` needs to be resolved, the `Page.GetDataItem()` method will give an exception with a message like

> Databinding methods such as `Eval()`, `XPath()`, and `Bind()` can only be used in the context of a databound control.

`DataBinder.Eval` still works in those circumstances because you provide it the target object manually, so ASP.NET doesn't need to do any resolving on its own.

Comment: when the following error occur like "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control." then we should be use <%#DataBinder.Eval%> instead of <%#Eval%>.

Answer (score 4):

the Eval method is just a shortcut of the latter

Answer (score -4):

I have seen following code

```
<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ApplicationId").ToString() == "-1" ? "N/A" : Eval("ApplicationId").ToString()) %>
```

So I guess they slightly different.