# Correct way to not use Eval in a repeater and improve performance?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, eval

I have a repeater which takes 270 seconds to render and actually ends up crashing all browsers.  The SQL to retrieve the data takes about 10 seconds.  I wanted to remove the Eval's to see if that speeds up things a bit, but I am having trouble with the correct syntax.  I have doubts that this would actually improve performance as I am dealing with 150,000 records.  Would a GridView or other control be faster? Would using LINQ to SQL improve performance?  Here is the code for the Eval:

```
<%#Eval("Name")%>
```

I am trying:

```
<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Name"]%>
```

But the above does not work.  It says DataRowView can't be used as an expression

I will also point out that there is no paging involved.

Comment: What type is your data source?

Comment: @jrummell - I have a method that pulls the SQL into a datatable and then binds that to the repeater. I am not using a SqlDataSource, ObjectDatasource, etc.

Comment: The problem here is not the Eval but the render to a table (and not divs), the data the are not lazy load, but load all together in memory, and the viewstate that you may have with the gridview.

Comment: @Aristos - I am little confused on what you said. I am using a DataTable, not a Table, unless you are saying that a repeater renders as an HTML table.  Are you saying that a GridView would be better?

Comment: @Xaisoft because you say that you crash the browser, I mean the `<table></table>` that the gridbiew is rendered. browsers have issue to render huge tables.

Comment: @Aristos - OK, How can I avoid this?  It is 150,000 records.

Comment: @Xaisoft try a repeater for start... and just render line by line... to see if browsers can handle it, also make a flush now and then...

Comment: you do not use any updatepanel... correct ? if you use remove that first.

Comment: @Arista - Can you put an example in code in an answer on how to do it line by line?  I am not using an updatepanel.

Comment: Can you use an IDataReader to read from your data store (if the data comes from a database) instead of a DataTable? That will reduce some overhead. Loading 150,000 rows of data into memory is not cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using either `Eval` or `Container.DataItem` is not going to make a difference since they are the same thing. please take a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270230/evalstate-or-databinder-evalcontainer-dataitem-state).

if your browser is crashing when displaying the data, that's because too much resulting html or javascript are being rendered at the browser. note that `Eval` is executed on server side, so it's not the root cause of browser crash.

i suggest using paging to improve both performance and avoid crashing. if you really can't use paging, how about having the user to download a csv file to open in excel or even a PDF file?

as for using Linq to SQL to improve performance, i assume you are comparing it with stored procedure or dynamic sql? stored procedure will always give you the best performance, but once your dynamic sql or linq expression (or compiled linq) is cached at sql server, they aren't that slow compare to sproc.

Comment: The link you provided compares Eval(“var”) %> or <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, “var”)%>.  A different way to do it w/out Eval is to use <%# ((Object)Container.DataItem).var%> , though having performance tested this I personally found no difference.